# JDBC result set type scroll sensitive

Tags: java, jdbc

How does `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` actually work in JDBC?

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                       ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                       ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: internal working of SENSITIVE resultset

Comment: Internal working?  Open the source code and look.  What do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: The result set is sensitive to changes made by others to the database that occur after the result set was created. this is standard definition of oracle docs. once resultset created will changes made in database reflect to the resultset?

Comment: you can learn here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html?is-external=true

Comment: no it wont. you execute a query at a given time and save the result in a so called result set. if you now change anything on the database, it wont change the result set unless you execute another query to update the result set

Comment: Thank you. This site explained in detail https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/resltse7.htm#1023726

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It depends, if the result set is actually `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, in some implementations you are able to see changes done either by the own connection or by others (depending on the transaction isolation level). That is the whole point of scroll sensitive.

Comment: The implementation is RDBMS dependent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54611564/4808122) the Oracle implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html) says:

> The type of a `ResultSet` object determines the level of its functionality
>   in two main areas: (1) the ways in which the cursor can be manipulated
>   and (2) how concurrent changes made to the underlying data source are
>   reflected by the `ResultSet` object. The latter is called the sensitivity
>   of the `ResultSet` object.
>
> The three different `ResultSet` types are described below.
>
> [...]
>
> **3.** `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>
> - The result set is scrollable; its cursor can move both forward and
>     backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an
>     absolute position.
> - The result set reflects changes made to the underlying data source
>     while the result set remains open.
>
> The default `ResultSet` type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.
>
> The method `DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType` returns `true`
>   if the specified type is supported by the driver and `false` otherwise.
>
> If the driver does not support the type supplied to the methods
>   `createStatement`, `prepareStatement`, or `prepareCall`, it generates an
>   `SQLWarning` on the `Connection` object that is creating the statement.
>   When the statement is executed, the driver returns a `ResultSet` object
>   of a type that most closely matches the requested type. An application
>   can find out the type of a `ResultSet` object by calling the method
>   `ResultSet.getType`.